# i am getting this ( T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING ) syntax error in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error

> (syntax error, unexpected '","' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING),
>   expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\offline Storage\online
>   form.php on line 14)

My code is...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['first'],$_POST['last'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['fdback']))
{
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root@localhost");

    mysql_select_db("feedback");
    $fname=$_POST['first'];
    $lname=$_POST['last'];
    $eml=$_POST['email'];
    $fdb=$_POST['fdback'];

    $result=mysql_query("insert into data values(".$fname",".$lname",".$eml",".$fdb")");

    if($result)
    {
        echo "Data Inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error"
    }
};

?>
```

Comment: you missid dot  .. after each var

Comment: can you please scpecify it please Thank You...

Comment: I have posted  and asnwer  for show you the code

Comment: Also missing semicolon after `echo "Error"`.  The missing dots mentioned are like `$fname . "," . $lname . ","...` but much more importantly, the `mysql_*()` functions were removed from new PHP versions 2 years ago and this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Using `prepare()/bindParam()/execute()` in PDO would have avoided the syntax problem while also producing safe code. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You missed  the dot after the vars for concat

```
$result=mysql_query("insert into data values(".$fname. ",".$lname. ",".$eml. ",".$fdb. ")");
```

But you should not use php var in sql code  .. you are at risk for sqlinjection  .. you should take a look at your mysql driver for binding param